# Optimizing C++ Vector for Search

Tags: c++, optimization

With my current project, I did my best to adhere to the principle that premature optimization is the root of all evil. However, now the code is tested, and it is time for optimization. I did some profiling, and it turns out my code spends almost 20% of its time in a function where it finds all possible children, puts them in a vector, and returns them. As a note, I am optimizing for speed, memory limitations are not a factor.

Right now the function looks like this:

```
void Board::GetBoardChildren(std::vector<Board> &children)
{
    children.reserve(open_columns_.size()); // only reserve max number of children

    UpdateOpenColumns();

    for (auto i : open_columns_)
    {
        short position_adding_to = ColumnToPosition(i);
        MakeMove(position_adding_to); // make the possible move
        children.push_back(*this); // add to vector of children
        ReverseMove(); // undo move
    }
}
```

According to the profiling, my code spends about 40% of the time just on the line `children.push_back(*this);` I am calling the function like this:

```
std::vector<Board> current_children;
current_state.GetBoardChildren(current_children);
```

I was thinking since the maximum number of possible children is small (7), would it be better to just use an array? Or is there not a ton I can do to optimize this function?

Comment: `children.push_back(*this)` makes a copy of the `Board` object. How expensive is making that copy?

Comment: @NPE The operation is pretty expensive, it is a fairly large object. However, I didn't see a way around making a copy. I am using a depth first algorithm, and as far as I'm aware, I need a fresh copy for each of the possible children.

Comment: I suspect this is where most of the time is going. I think the vector itself is a red herring.

Comment: @SidharthMudgal No, I am not accessing by index. I had always been under the impression that for small collections, like this one, `List` was more expensive because it is doubly linked

Comment: Is `Board::Board(Board const&)` actually implemented (and not inlined) or is C++ using the generic copy constructor? That would explain why the profiler is pointing you to the line with `push_back` instead of the actual copy constructor.

Comment: @bitmask It is using the default copy constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your responses to my comments, it seems very likely that most of the time is spent copying the board in

```
children.push_back(*this);
```

You need to find a way to avoid making all those copies, or a way to make them cheaper.

Simply changing the vector into an array or a list will likely not make any difference to performance.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll go back and take a look at the algorithm and see if I can cut down on the copies. Is there more to "making them cheaper" than just cutting down on the size? I'm using a default copy constructor.

Comment: @Kyryx: It depends on the contents of the `Board` class. For example, if it contains some fields that are identical between boards and immutable, copying them by pointer rather than by value would probably be cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

The most important question is: Do you really need all States at once inside current_state?
If you just iterate over them once or twice in the default order, then there is no need for a vector, just generate them on demand.

If you really need it, here is the next step.  Since `Board` is expensive for copying, a `DifferenceBoard` that keeps only track of the difference may be better. Pseudocode:

```
struct DifferenceBoard { // or maybe inherit from Board that a DifferenceBoard
                         // can be built from another DifferenceBoard
  Board *original;
  int fromposition, toposition;
  State state_at_position;

  State get(int y, int x) const {
    if ((x,y) == fromposition) return Empty;
    if ((x,y) == toposition  ) return state_at_position;
    return original->get();
  }
};
```